# Detect coordinates of touchpad

Tags: vbscript, coordinates, autoit, detect, touchpad

I want to develop something like Synaptics touchpad gesture application. The Synaptics settings show x and y coordinates. Is there any software I can use? Like this code:

```
$x_start = 300
$y_start = 300
While 1
   If $ontouch == True Then
     MouseMove($x_start + $x_touch, $y_start + $y_touch)
   EndIf
Wend
```

You can suggest any language but preferably in AutoIt or VBScript. Some images for clarification:

[image: Tap input]

[image: Tap output]

Comment: You can take a look at this ==> [Live updates of the Mouse Position in HTML/HTA Document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658970/live-updates-of-the-mouse-position-in-html-hta-document?answertab=active#tab-top)